# Sample code for searching text in PDF using LUCENE 4.6 and PDF Box

Tags: lucene, pdfbox

Iam using LUCENE 4.6 for searching phrase in PDF. I have written the following code. But it is throwing error in "Analyser" and "QueryPhrase" lines. Please help me in doing this.

```
            Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer(Version.LUCENE_44);

            // Store the index in memory:               
            Directory directory = new RAMDirectory();
            // To store an index on disk, use this instead:
            //Directory directory = FSDirectory.open("/tmp/testindex");
            IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_44, analyzer);
            IndexWriter iwriter = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
            Document doc = new Document();
            String text = "This is the text to be indexed.";
            doc.add(new Field("fieldname", text, TextField.TYPE_STORED));
            iwriter.addDocument(doc);
            iwriter.close();

            // Now search the index
            DirectoryReader ireader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
            IndexSearcher isearcher = new IndexSearcher(ireader);
            // Parse a simple query that searches for "text":
            QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_44, "fieldname", analyzer);
            Query query = parser.parse("text");
            ScoreDoc[] hits = isearcher.search(query, null, 1000).scoreDocs;
            // Iterate through the results:
            if(hits.length>0){
                System.out.println("Searched text existed in the PDF.");
            }
            ireader.close();
            directory.close();
         }
         catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
         }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot instantiate abstract class Analyzer. Instead you could write something like:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new EnglishAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_44);
```

Comment: Also you might need to add these libraries into CLASSPATH: 
`<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
 <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
 <version>4.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
 <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
 <version>4.6.0</version>
</dependency>
`

Comment: tried with above statement as well but still facing the problem..it is not resolving the issue.

Comment: Do you have runtime or compile error ? Do you have these libraries in the classpath: lucene-analyzers-common, lucene-queryparser ?

Comment: I have resolved the issue. Now for searching the sentence in the pdf iam using queryparser. But while constructing the query it is taking only the first word in the sentence and saying tht the sentence is not existed in PDF.I used the following code.
 QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT,"contents", analyzer);      queryParser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND);
          queryParser.setPhraseSlop(0);
          Query query=queryParser.createPhraseQuery("contents",sentence);
          ScoreDoc[] hits = isearcher.search(query, null, 1000).scoreDocs;